# Mass self-annihilates to violate law of conservation of energy?

Tags: gravity, conservation-laws, mass-energy, antimatter

The scenario is this: a large mass $ M $ is made of matter and anti-matter in equal amounts. If given a little energy, it will self-annihilate. Another mass $ m $ is in vicinity. The potential energy of both systems is given by:

$$ U = -\frac{GMm}{r^2} $$

Both of them have gravitational potential energy. Now, the larger mass self-annihilates almost instantaneously, where $ E=Mc^2 $. How does the gravitational potential energy alter the path of photons so that the law of conservation of energy remains intact?

If antimatter has negative mass, this implies there is no potential and hence the law of conservation of energy isn't violated. But if it has positive mass, this means that photons released will be under effect from the potential energy?

Comment: *"If antimatter has negative mass..."* Antimatter does **not** have negative mass. Nothing has negative mass. Antimatter in mainstream physics has positive mass and the opposite charge of the conventional particle. E.g., positron has opposite charge from electron, but both have positive mass.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say that the large mass $M$ is made of $M/2$ anti-matter and $M/2$ ordinary matter located in a very tiny space. Small mass $m$ is very far at distance $r$ from $m$ (also very localized). The potential energy if everything is stationary, slow, and far away is
$$-\frac{GmM}{r}.$$

Now suppose anti-matter and ordinary matter annihilate in a very symmetrical fashion. An instant just after the collision, mass $m$ does not detect any change, it has to wait $c/r$ seconds for it to notice (the gravitational waves propagate to update the field). Meanwhile, about $Mc^2$ amounts of energy were converted into photons that travel radially in all directions and decay in intensity as the distance squared.

After a while. The mass $m$ will feel zero gravitational potential and the whole initial energy ($Mc^2-GmM/r$) were diluted into the universe by the photons and gravitational waves.